# InDesign: Replace each find match instance with an increasing value

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have a text with a lot of reference notes. The original text simply has asterisks(*) to indicate the presence of a note, but I need to change these to serial letter values like footnote references (a, b, c, etc.)

Is there a way to select all the text on the page, find all asterisks, and replace them in a serial sequence? So the first instance gets replaced with a, the second with b, the third with c, and so on? If not with letters, I could use number values instead, and then do a second round of replacing 1 with a, 2 with b, 3 with c, etc.

I tried using the find/replace list script, but I can't figure out how to do this in sequence. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Note: I'm not using the inbuilt footnotes feature for a variety of reasons, so that's not an option.

One thought I have is a script that basically says "find *" one time and "replace with a", then stop. Then again, "find *" one time and "replace with b", stop. And just repeat that sequence until no more matches are found. The find/replace list script seems to operate on a "change all" basis, so it finds all * and replaces them all with a. I need to change it to "change one". If anyone knows how to write a basic script like this I would be so grateful for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following script does the trick, provided by mike41294032 on the Adobe forum:

```
app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = "*";

var finds = app.activeDocument.selection[0].findText();
if (finds.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < finds.length; i++){  
   finds[i].contents = String(i+1);
  }  
}
app.findTextPreferences = app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
```